# Total Sum dependent on two filters/slicers

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table with many fields, including year and region. I need total sum for sales per region and Year, and I want these total sums to be responsive to year/region filter/slicer Only; all other fields will not affect the Total sum.

PS. ALLEXCEPT doesn't work well, because I have a lot of fields

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsBfm.png

Edit: i'm looking solution for PowerPivot (not for PowerBI); Data Model is base for pivots.

Comment: Edit your question in order to be readable. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put your measure on the report in a KPI visual for example. Next put all your slicers on the report.

Then click on your slicer which should not filter the measure and go to (at the main menue) `Format > Edit Interactions`. Now you will see on your KPI visual these two sympols:

[image]

Click the right one and it will get grey. This means the sliver you have selected does now not interact with this KPI visual.

Do this for the other slicers as well, which should not interact with the KPI visual. All the other slicers will interact with your KPI visual.

You can test it and you will see the value in the KPI visual changes (or not) depending which interaction type is selected on the slicer.

Comment: Strawberryshrub this is great solution, but in powerPivot i don't have options for choosing which slicer interact (or not) with data;
My (bad) formula for thisL CALCULATE(SUM('Brand PnL'[Sales]);FILTER('Brand PnL';'Brand PnL'[Region]='Brand PnL'[Region]);FILTER('Brand PnL';'Brand PnL'[Year]='Brand PnL'[Year]))

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like group by (region,year) then sum :

```
Sum For Selected Year and region =
SUMX(SUMMARIZE(FactSales,FactSales[keyregion],FactSales[keyYear]),[Total Sales])
```